# Uncaught object error with Karma

Tags: requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am pretty new to jasmine and karma, but I have a rails app set up using requirejs and jasmine and I'm trying to get karma up and running.  I have it running, but when I run the unit.js config file, I get the following error.

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux)]: Connected on socket PFOOqf9ZbOB_Tv7zhugx with id 60346244
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux) ERROR
  Uncaught object
  at /home/parallels/Code/Test/src/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141

WARN [web-server]: 404: /people.js
WARN [web-server]: 404: /jquery.js
WARN [web-server]: 404: /page.js
WARN [web-server]: 404: /dropzone.js
```

Line 141 in require.js is

```
 function defaultOnError(err) {
        throw err; //<-- this is 141
    }
```

Here is my karma unit.js config file.

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Jul 10 2014 08:25:37 GMT-0400 (EDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '../../..',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      { pattern: 'spec/javascripts/extensions/*_spec.js', included: true },
        { pattern: 'spec/javascripts/*_spec.js', included: true }
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {

    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, but based on the 404 messages, I'm guessing it might have something to do with requirejs not being able to find those 4 javascript files.  If I manually run my jasmine specs they all run fine, so I'm not quite sure where/why it's breaking down.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Edit:

I have updated my code based on the karma+requireJS documentation.  It seems like it's gotten me further along, but now I just get a generic error without much of a message to know what's going on.

When I run the karma test I get this....

```
karma start spec/karma/config/unit.js 
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux)]: Connected on socket OwrWtfnBJ4zB6DERU0cI with id 70596022
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.004 secs / 0 secs)
```

My folder structure is as follows

```
src
--app
----assets
------javascripts
--------application.js, global.js,page.js, routes.js, people.js, etc
--spec
----javascripts
------*_spec.js
----karma
------config
--------unit.js, test-main.js
--vendor
----assets
------javascripts
--------dropzone.js, icheck.js, jquery-ui.js, mustache.js
```

Comment: what does your folder structure look like?

Comment: I think there's a problem with your test-main.js file: have you followed the [karma+requireJS documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/plus/requirejs.html)?